# This works BUT WHY?

Tags: python

I'm learing Python on codecademy and came across this solution for a function that's meant to remove duplicates from a list of numbers:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 2]

def remove_duplicates(x):
    p = []
    for i in x:
       if i != i:
           p.append(i)
    return i
```

I ran this in pycharm with some print statements and just got an empty list. I'm only curious because when I do this in my head, it makes no sense, but codecademy accepts this as an answer. Is it just a fluke? Or is this on a level I don't understand yet?

Comment: this may be used only filter out NaNs if you return `p`, otherwise doesn't make sense.

Comment: doesn't make sense to me too.

Comment: Got my head scratching as well.

Comment: It doesn't work - the question is, why does codeacademy think it works? And for the answer, I guess you'd have to ask them.

Comment: I get just `2` (not a list, an integer) both in Py3 and Py2, as I would expect from seeing the code.

Comment: What is the function supposed to return?  The number of non-duplicate items?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what the function supposed to return is `[1,2]`, am I correct?

Comment: My suspicion is that the function is supposed to return number of unique duplicates, and perhaps code academy thinks it's correct because it returns `2` (which is correct for the number of unique duplicates). The code however, is completely illogical.

Comment: @Karin: Actually, I just found the challenge.  It is expecting a list, but it does indeed validate this solution: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HCgPH.png

Comment: The challenge is here: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-rCQKw/2/4

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Good to know I'm not the only one. I should have said before, but Eduard got it. It's supposed to return a list of [1, 2]. I'll have to bug codecademy about this.

Comment: Pretty much anything passes the challenge. `print 'hi'` [passes](https://i.imgur.com/ZnZ7H3o.png).

Comment: @Blorgbeard that don't work for me, but `return 0` does

Comment: @Copperfield you don't even need to define a function - see my link. Either way, it's clearly CodeAcademy's fault eh.

Comment: @Blorgbeard by using the link of zondo, it ask me to define the function...

Comment: @Copperfield huh, you're right. But once I defined a function and submitted it, I could remove it and a bare `print hi` succeeded from then on.

Comment: @Blorgbeard wow, indeed... you only need to pass once and then anything else passes, you can even remove everything and that pass too.... this is quite amusing :)

Answer (score 4):

You are correct: it doesn't make any sense.  First, it creates a list called `p` that gets each item that is not equal to itself.  The only object that I know of that is not equal to itself is NaN, but you don't have any of those, so `p` is just an empty list.  Defining `p` is useless, however, because it isn't even returned.  What is returned is `i`, which is assigned to each item in the last, so it is the last item in the list by the end of the function.  In short, that function is equivalent to this:

```
def remove_duplicates(x):
    return x[-1]
```

I haven't heard what the function is supposed to return, but perhaps it is supposed to return the number of non-duplicate items.  If it is, it "works" just because the last item in the list happens to be the number of non-duplicate items.

Comment: Even throws an error if the list is empty. Although not the *same* error as `x[-1]`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions, zondo.

Comment: @jpmc26: True, a `NameError`.  I suppose I should have said *roughly* equivalent.

Comment: Oh, by no means was that a criticism. Just an oddity.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to this snippet to see the pythonic way to remove duplicated (good_result) and also to understand why your code doesn't make any sense:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 2]


def remove_duplicates(x):
    p = []
    for i in x:
        if i != i:
            p.append(i)
    return i

good_result = list(set(x))
print good_result
print remove_duplicates(x)
```

As you can see, your function is not returning the filtered list without duplicate values, it's just returning the last element of the list (index=-1). So codeacademy shouldn't accept that snippet as a valid answer to the question `how to remove duplicateds from a list` for sure.

Now, if we assume what codeacademy was really asking is for `the number of unique values from a list`, then is a casuality your broken code gives the right answer, which is the same as `len(good_result)`. It worked just by luck just to say, it doesn't mean your code is correct :)

Comment: Thanks, BPL. Your solution is similar to a lot of what I've seen. Not sure what that guy was thinking with that, or why it gets acceptable as an answer.

Comment: @ThomasCho Me neither... I've edited my comment adding some suspicious I've got about why codeacademy confirmed a wrong answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

your code just returns the last element of the number, that is same as

```
return x[-1]
```

It doesn't return a list.
I think you need to check the question that they may be asking like,

a)function to return one of the duplicating element in a list.

b)function to return the no of duplicating elements in a list.

for the above two questions your answer is 2, by luck the answer is correct.